# Searching values in a large matrix

Tags: python, matrix, large-data

Im working with python 3.5 and Im writing a script that handles large spreadsheet files. Each row of the spreadsheet contains a phrase and several other relevant values. I'm parsing the file as a matrix, but for the example file, it has over 3000 rows (and even larger files should be within expected). I also have a list of 100 words. I need to search for each word, which row of the matrix contains it in its string, and print the some averages based on that.

Currently I'm iterating over each row of the matrix, and then check if the string contains any of the mentioned words, but this process takes 3000 iterations, with 100 checks for each one. Is there any better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: have you tried parallelizing the task?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example code, small matrix with the same format as real one, a short list of words to search and expected output?

Comment: Depending on the scale of your problem, is it possible to use another solution, e.g. database like MySQL? You may then simply `SELECT` on the query strings you care about, then perform the operation on the associated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run, I would encourage you to use something more suitable for the task. A SQL database, for instance.

But if you stick with writing your own python solution, here are some things you can do to optimize it:

**Use sets.** Sets have a very efficient membership check.

```
wordset_100 = set(worldlist_100)

for row in data_3k:
    word_matches = wordset_100.intersect(row.phrase.split(" "))
    for match in word_matches:
        # add to accumulator
        # this loop will be run less than len(row.phrase.split(' ')) times
        pass
```

**Parallelize.**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import defaultdict


def matches(wordset_100, row):
    return wordset_100.intersect(row.phrase.split(" ")), row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    accu = defaultdict(int)
    p = Pool()
    wordset_100 = set(worldlist_100)
    for m, r in p.map(matches, data_3k):
        for word in m:
            accu[word] += r.number
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't thought of parallelizing the task